# Apple photos. Storage options

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I have about 1.5gb of historic photos I'd like to add to iCloud so they can face recognition, searchable and viewable on my apple devices. I'm prepared to pay for the 2Tb storage.

However, I don't want *every* photo I take on my phone automatically added to iCloud photos because there will be duff pics etc

How do I do the first part, and how do I prevent the second part happening?

Any help apppreciated!

Comment: Are you sure if you add the photos as files, outside of iCloud Photos, that face recognition will work?  I believe that feature only works in Photos (thus, synced to every Apple device).

Comment: @fsb That makes sense. Would I need to add these photos into the photos app in OSX for it to then process the recognition then upload to the cloud? That’s fine but I don’t want every new photo added when taken on my iPhone. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that will work.  Face recognition is only available in Photos. You're trying to do something that system isn't designed to do. iCloud is a sync system.

Comment: @fsb If they import the old pictures into Photos (as they said in the comment), face recognition will work

Comment: You can disable iCloud Photos on the iPhone. This will prevent both upload and download.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside makes sense. I’ve got a lot of photos but could put them on an external drive and point the Photos App Library there I guess.

Comment: @nohillside OP doesn't want to import them into Photos (to do the face recognition) because they'll be synced to all other devices.  If iCloud Photos is turned off & the images imported on the device to do face recognition, then I thought that recognition is gone once the images are moved out of Photos and then OP wouldn't be able to search by person. It's a great question and one I never thought about.

Comment: @fsb Their first paragraph mentions access from all devices, the second wants to avoid upload of phone pictures. Don‘t see why they can‘t import **on their Mac** to trigger face recognition.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, that will work but it won't be searchable or viewable from other devices, right? At least that's my understanding (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @fsb It wouldn't be viewable from the iPhone, right.

Comment: @nohillside I'm guessing here since I haven't tried this but I'm thinking it wouldn't be viewable on any other device except the Mac.

Comment: @fsb If they disable iCloud Photo sync only on the iPhone, it should sync between Mac, iPad and iCloud without problems

Comment: @nohillside true but then no other image will sync to the other devices and it also wouldn't meet the OP's requirement of it being available on all their Apple devices.

Comment: Thanks @fsb - gonna test this and let you know

Comment: hey @fsb Thanks for the advice. It didn't really work tbh, and I think what I want doesn't exist within the Apple ecosystem. Wish they'd allow face recognition meta data added to photos on an iMac (for example) to be shared into iCloud then useable on any device. On device processing is cool from a privacy POV for sure, but not so much from a UX perspective

Comment: Also, thanks to @nohillside for the advice